# Why does PRAGMA always keep the same value after i clean data?

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts, android-contentprovider

I am testing the `onUpgrade` method in `ContactsProvider`.

When i clean the `ContactsProvider` data from setting->application->contacts storage->clean data, and launch `contacts` again. The `user_version` variable still keep the value before cleaning.

For example: The original `user_version` is 354, and i increment it by one through `PRAGMA user_version=355`. And then clean data. Launch contacts. The `user_version` is still 355.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Doc of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html),

> The PRAGMA statement is an SQL extension specific to SQLite and used to modify the operation of the SQLite library or to query the SQLite library for internal (non-table) data.